# Email style issue without margin-top

Tags: css, html-email

anyone has an idea of styling this image in email?
[image]

So the tricky part is to add the different background color around the center white jobs section. The easiest way is to use margin-top: -120px; against this job section. Other approaches such as using position: absolute/float might be okay for regular browser. However, none of these work in email/gmail.

Anyone can help? Thanks!

---------- edited --------

Probably I can use the two-colors background as a whole background image. The thing is this image needs to be long enough to support the left bottom content. Just wondering if there're better options available.

------- edited/ add the html & css as Geeky asked ----

This is the html http://pastebin.com/nNJcyTrG

This is the css http://pastebin.com/7rhKcbYa

So the middle white job section starts at following in the html

```
<table align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="bix-mail-middle">
```

Comment: Add your html and css ..so that we can help u better

Comment: Thanks Geeky -- the html & css has been attached.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get this working by creating a background image to include the two colors. Then repeat the background image in the x direction. This can cover the middle white job section.

For the rest bottom content, just use the regular background-color, and then everything works fine.

So the trick here is to use pre-defined background image to achieve the position effect.